# Need help writing a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to get the results for each of the following queries into one query. I know I can do a union but I was wondering if there is a better way because each table has different columns? Thanks

```
select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_ROLES where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_PLATFORMS where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_COMPETENCIES where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_TECH_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_MGR_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from USER_APPS where TEST_IND ='Y'

select distinct RESOURCE_ID from BUS_PROCS where TEST_IND ='Y'
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? There is no way to write a query where each row has different columns.

Comment: I think UNION is the best way to go....

Comment: And you looking for one row with many columns (RoleId, PlatformId, ...) or many rows with one column?

Comment: I am looking for all the unique users (resource_ID) that have test_ind ='y' in all those tables.

Comment: What columns do you want to return? Show the expected output in your question.

Comment: you can use join so you can have only one where clause.

Comment: Well lets say the RESOURCE_ID Column has Jim and George in  the USER_ROLES table. And the USER_PLATFORMS table has George and Mike in the Resource_ID column. I would like the results to return: Jim, George, Mike.

Comment: I've seen examples of Inner Joins with only 2 or 3 tables. How would you do that with more tables?

Comment: You don't want an inner join for what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you doing some kind of join just to make the query shorter, you're going to be creating a very large temporary table that just appends all the tables. That would be expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you say you don't want a UNION query, nothing in your requirements as described in the comments precludes it. It is okay if the tables have different columns as long as the columns you select are the same across all the tables.

**This is what you need**

```
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_ROLES where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_PLATFORMS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_COMPETENCIES where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_TECH_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_MGR_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_APPS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from BUS_PROCS where TEST_IND ='Y'
```

**Note:** I took out the distinct clauses, the union will make the result distinct anyway so it is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is your best option here, it will automatically remove duplicates from the result set, if you want to keep the duplicated you can use `UNION ALL`.

```
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_ROLES where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_PLATFORMS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_COMPETENCIES where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_TECH_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_MGR_SKILLS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from USER_APPS where TEST_IND ='Y'
UNION
select RESOURCE_ID from BUS_PROCS where TEST_IND ='Y'
```

[UNION MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: As JohnFx says, the DISTINCTs are unnecessary. Dupes are discarded automatically in this scenario unless the writer uses UNION ALL.

Comment: Your right, even I said that. Just forgot to remove them.. Done now..

Answer (score -1):

Other than the unions already mentioned, you could use a multi-statement table-valued function: define a table variable and SELECT INTO from your multitude of queries, then select * from functionName().  You would still need each query to produce the same columns with the same data types, however, so you may need to cast/convert the round pegs into the square, columnar holes.